# rearranging values from array

Tags: php, arrays, date

My array

```
<?
    $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28','16-03-14','16-03-28','16-04-14','16-04-28',
'16-05-14','16-05-28','16-06-14','16-06-28','16-07-14','16-07-28','16-08-14','16-08-28','16-09-14','16-09-28','16-10-14','16-10-28',
'16-11-14','16-11-28','16-12-14','16-12-28');
    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');

    ?>
```

Here is what my code looks like for selecting from the array the value however when it selects it from the array it doesn't format it into the correct format is there a way I can echo out the end date in the format like this `mm/dd/yy` instead of `yy-mm-dd`Thankyou.

```
<?php
$statement_date_timestamp = strtotime($statement_date);
$nextdate = "";
for($i = 0; $i<sizeof($date); $i++)
{
    if(strtotime($date[$i]) == $statement_date_timestamp)
        $nextdate = $date[$i+1];
}
echo'End Date:';
echo $nextdate;
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [date()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function to format the timestamp in any way you want:

```
echo date('d/m/y', strtotime($nextdate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `DateTime` instance with the input format and the input date, then convert to the output format:

```
$nextdate = DateTime::createFromFormat('y-m-d', $nextdate)->format('m-d-y');
```

Comment: you're welcome. PS. note that `$nextdate = $date[$i+1]` may access an element beyond the upper bound of the `$date` array, given the `for` loop counts `$i` up to `sizeof($date)`

Answer (score 0):

I think that all your code can be shortened:

```
$statement_date = date( 'y-m-d', strtotime( $statement_date ) );
$date_found     = array_search( $statement_date, $date );
$nextdate       = $date[$date_found+1];

echo date( 'm/d/y', strtotime($nextdate) );
```

I have used `date()` to format `$statement_date` because I don't know its format, but if it is `y-m-d` you can directly search for it.

`array_search()` return the corresponding key, then you obtain `$nextdate` incrementing key by 1.

To format `$nextdate` you can use `date()` or `DateTime->format()`, as per other answers.

---

- Read more about [array_search()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)
- Read more about [DateTime class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)